# javascript vs templating language

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

In developing large html pages with plenty of nested div's I found myself debugging the closing `</div>` tags. To get around this I started using javascript:

```
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
```

Then I would simply use `div1.appendChild(somethingElse)` to build the page, happy to never again worry about closing those DIV tags. As I progressed writing, I started enjoying making the html pages from javascript, letting the browser render the html from javascript.

Then my js code became unmanageable, with js all over the place. This brought me into looking at frameworks to get my code to the next level, which I have decided to incorporate backbone.js. This will help with developing a single page app.

To implement backbone.js, I needed a whole bunch of up to date tutorials and books.  It seems like all tutorials are recommending template language/library like handlebars, ejs, jade, etc.

I feel that this puts me back to debugging DIV tags.

My question then becomes can I choose to not use a templating language for the views and build the view using javascript? Did I miss a larger issue in wanting to do this? Any examples, tutorials, out there?

I guess I should add that I may want someone else to help with the code, so I know readability might be an issue, if not 'the' issue.

Comment: wow this seems like a terribly lazy issue to have, no offense. maybe look into a web framework like ruby on rails or django to help extract some of the more "boring" parts of creating views in to the framework's functionality..

Comment: Sounds like you're putting everything in JS, and the html contains nothing but an include statement.  Don't do that.

Comment: @ergonaut Yes, that is exactly what I am doing, very little html. Not understanding the 'why not'... instead of a long string I have objects

Comment: what you are doing is fine. it might be more work to code views, but it will work just fine and even has some advantages, namely tying events and own properties to spawned element objects. it also means you're not limited by one template's abilities versus another; you have full js to compose the view. you can address your complexity by making smaller partial view generators as named functions or with a variety of other code-management techniques.

Comment: Try to use IDEs with support on detecting partner tags. You could also use Jade so that you won't need to close tags anymore.

Comment: Just get a good editor for HTML that will inform you anytime you have mismatched tags.  Only creating your page programmatically with client-side Javascript will leave you with a new SEO problem to figure out how to solve.

Comment: My code is all back end, so I never think about SEO. Will my view created by javascript be able to be read by robots?

Comment: I hear the callouts on the IDE. I hope to stick to a just better than simple text editor.

Comment: @Craig - `document.createElement()` is NOT back-end code.  That's code that runs in a browser (front-end) unless you're using some back-end framework that simulates a DOM.  HTML created via Javascript in the browser is usually not readable by robots because they don't usually actually run your Javascript - they just look at the source of the page.

Comment: @jfriend00, Looks like that is one possible downfall in running it at the front-end. I'm guessing another downfall would be that I am providing users my code. I am however working on moving to node.js. I therefore am **assuming** that my views will get rendered to html on the back end.

Comment: Moving to node.js will allow you to change how you build your pages to use a wide ranging set of options for building the pages server-side (as you could do with any back-end dev environment).  I personally use handlebars for template rendering in node.js and I strongly recommend you find an editor that will help you write legal templates too.